# swift - Twilio Video Chat - Alert when freezes

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am implementing video chat feature with Twilio iOS SDK
Call is working great but I would like to display for the recipient if the other one is not currently in video chat (instead of displaying the regular freeze static image that comes up when you're not broadcasting anymore).

I am trying to send the command to stop streaming as soon as app enters background but this does not seem to come through and user still gets the static image of the other one so we can't display some label for this.

Any thoughts or someone with similar issues?

Kind Regards,

Martin

Comment: Have you implemented `room:participantDidDisconnect` for your `TVIRoomDelegate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from their support which solved the issue:

Our TVICameraCapturer does not automatically enable/disable TVILocalVideoTrack in response to interruptions. However, it's easy to implement this yourself using TVICameraCapturerDelegate.

```
extension ViewController : TVICameraCapturerDelegate {
    func cameraCapturer(_ capturer: TVICameraCapturer, didStartWith source: TVICameraCaptureSource) {
        // Layout the camera preview with dimensions appropriate for our orientation.
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()

        if (!localVideoTrack.isEnabled) {
            localVideoTrack.isEnabled = true;
        }
    }

    func cameraCapturerWasInterrupted(_ capturer: TVICameraCapturer, reason: AVCaptureSessionInterruptionReason) {
        localVideoTrack.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!